# How do I determine the current leasing mode of an SMB share?

Tags: windows-server-2016, server-message-block

I am preparing to migrate files from a Windows Server 2016 server to a new Windows Server 2022 server.  There is a complicated set of NTFS and Share permissions that I need to replicate.  I have found that the Microsoft "Storage Migration Service" tool will not work for my scenario (it doesn't correctly handle share permissions granted to local groups).  I am preparing to instead more manually export the existing share definitions and create corresponding new shares.  However, I cannot figure out how to determine the current Leasing Mode of the existing shares.  This attribute does not appear to be displayed by the Get-SMBShare Powershell cmdlet, and I can't identify it in the registry entries.

Any ideas on how to verify the current Leasing Mode?

Answer (score 0):

The LeaseMode is stored in the CSCFlags part of the share data structure in the registry at:

`HKLM\System\CurrentControlset\Services\LanmanServer\Shares\sharename`

Full,Shared,None

Full is the default, assume it is the setting if not configured.

`Shared = 4096, (0x00001000)`

`None= 131072 (0x00020000)`

CSCFlags is a bitmask flags enum.

You can see the values in the registry when you double click on the value and open it.

https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/6/C/C6C3C6F1-E84A-44EF-82A9-49BD3AAD8F58/Windows/%5BMS-SMB2-Diff%5D.pdf

---

You can also use Get-SmbShare and query for the specific share name, using the -LeasingMode switch to specify either Shared or None. If the share is configured that way, you will receive a successful result with the share details.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation of the CSCFlags value; I saw it in registry but couldn't find any info on how to interpret it.

As far as I can see, the -LeasingMode switch is not available on Windows Server 2016, though it is on later versions.

Comment: @MHerbener: it was introduced in Windows Server 2019. It enables emulating old file server semantics for old applications that previously were system wide global settings.

Comment: Do you mean that on my source Windows Server 2016 there is no per-share leasing mode, and therefore your original answer does not apply?

Comment: It neds to be OS build number 16215 or later. Should be easy enough to test by creating a share.

Comment: Probably formally introduced as a feature in 2019. The audience is small, but it is easier/more friendly to have it on a per share basis.

Comment: I think you are saying that in Windows Server 2016 leasing mode was server-wide and could not be configured on a per-share basis.  Assuming that is correct, how is server-wide leasing mode configured in Windows Server 2016 and how can I determine the current configuration of a Server 2016 installation?